# Problems with 3D matrices in Concert CPLEX C++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, linear-programming, cplex

I'm currently implementing [this model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlmDz.png) for an assignment in Operational Research and I'm founding some problems that I think are related with the variables' definitions. I read and watched many references about how to implement a 3D matrix, but I'm still getting the same error and don't know what else can I do to solve it.

The error I'm getting is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taE5P.png):

```
Empty Handle in IloArray::operator[]
ConcertTest: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1261/concert/include/ilconcert/iloenv.h:2232: 
X& IloArray<X>::operator[](IloInt) [with X= IloNumArray; 
IloInt = long int]: Assertion '(_impl) || (std:: cerr << "Empty Handle in IloArray::operator[]" 
<< std:: endl, ilo_stop_assert())' faield. 
Aborted (core dumped)

Process returned 134 (0x86) execution time: 0.094 s
```

The code for the variables is the follow:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IloEnv env;
    try{
        IloModel model(env);
        IloExpr obj(env);
        IloRangeArray constraints(env);

        // Defining the type of arrays

        typedef IloArray< IloArray<IloNumVarArray> > IloNumVarArray3;
        typedef IloArray< IloArray<IloNumArray> > IloNumArray3;
        typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> IloNumArray2;

        // Creating the variables

        IloInt N = 10;
        IloInt J = 10;
        IloInt W = 3;


        IloNumVarArray3 x_iwj(env, N);

        IloNumArray3 c_iwj(env, N);
        IloNumArray3 ce_iwj(env, N);
        IloNumArray3 cb_iwj(env, N);

        IloNumArray2 cap_iw(env, N);
        IloNumArray dem_j(env, J);

        // Definig the variables

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int w = 0; w < W; w++){
                x_iwj[i][w].add(IloNumVarArray(env, N, 0, IloInfinity, ILOINT));
                c_iwj[i][w] = IloNumArray(env, N);
                ce_iwj[i][w] = IloNumArray(env, N);
                cb_iwj[i][w] = IloNumArray(env, N);
                for(int j = 0; j < J; j++){
                    if(i == 0 && w == 2){
                        c_iwj[i][w][j] = 100;
                    }
                    else{
                        c_iwj[i][w][j] = 10; //rand() % 10;
                    }
                    ce_iwj[i][w][j] = 0.5; //rand() % 1;
                    cb_iwj[i][w][j] = 0.4; //rand() % 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            cap_iw[i] = IloNumArray(env, N);
            for(int w = 0; w < W; w++){
                cap_iw[i][w] = 150; //rand() % 150;
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < J; j++){
            dem_j[j] = 480; //rand() % 500;
        }

        ...
```

It may also be related with other parts of the code, so if necessary I can put it here.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Firstly, where in your code does the error occur? I can guess, but please tell us. Also, what are the index values when the error occurs? It looks to me like you might be trying to create some of the values for the second or third dimensions of the arrays before you have created the space in the first dimension to hold them.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply.
The error happens when I run the code. I think the problem is exactly it's not creating the matrix properly. Also, you're probably correct about not creating the first dimension, Do you know how can I solve that?